# removing a slide from left then add another one from right

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, slick.js

I'm trying to remove previous slide and then create another slide afterwards with :

```
$(".element").slick('slickRemove', currentSlide-1);
$(".element").slick('slickAdd', stringToAdd);
```

on `afterChange`

The problem is, the next slide after the current one will be skipped. any idea how to fix this?